# Running several name-based web sites on a single IP address

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, ubuntu-12.04

I have a public IP address and a domain name and they are properly binded. How can i create subdomains? I'm doing this to make a subdomain www.sub1.exaple.com runs ASP.NET 4.0 while the other subdomain www.sub2.example.com runs on different host config

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/sub1
ServerName www.sub1.example.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/sub2
ServerName www.sub2.example.com

</VirtualHost>
```

But i got an error of **"NameVirtualHost *:80 has no virtual hosts"** when i issue a commend "service apache2 restart"

Comment: I see no immediately obvious error in the above configuration. Could you post the file without redacting the rest of the information? (You don't need to include all comments, just the actual directives.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the first and second line. I don't know which webserver you use.

But in apache you have to create a new file under **"/etc/apache2/sites-available"**. There you can create a new vhost file. Give them a name you want.

Put you vhost information in this file something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/sub1
    ServerName www.sub1.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

After that you have to enable the vhost.

```
a2ensite nameofthefile
```

With this command you create a symlink from **"sites-available"** to **"sites-enabled"** then reload you webserver and it should work.